Please help me with my verilog code for processor (extension)
This is an extension to my previous question.
I am an undergraduate student and am new to Verilog.  I am writing Verilog code which simulates a processor along with registerFiles and memory (instruction + data memory).
Here is the instruction format:

All my modules only contact the processor, not anything else.
They are instantiated here:

within the processor . I use the processor to fetch values into my local registers and send them to ALU...
Could you please look at the code below?
module Processor();// will decode incoming instruction from  instruction file

//instruction decoding variables
reg [5:0]pc;
wire [31:0]instruction;
reg [6:0]Op;
reg [5:0]rd;
reg [5:0]rs1;
reg [5:0]destReg;
reg [5:0]rs2;
reg [6:0]func7;
reg [2:0]func3;
reg [11:0]imm;


//mem variables
reg [31:0]LocationFetchORStore;
wire [31:0]FetchedMemData;
reg [31:0]storeData;

//reg file variables
reg Operation;
reg [5:0]inputreg;
reg [31:0]value;
wire [31:0]contents;


//alu variables
reg [31:0]dataRS1;
reg [31:0]dataRS2;
wire [31:0]dataDest;


InstructMem instMem(.pc(pc),.instruction(instruction)); //IF

registerFile rfa(.Operation(Operation),.inputreg(inputreg), .value(value),.contents(contents));//ID/RF

ALU alu(.Op(Op),.a1(dataRS1),.b1(dataRS2),.result(dataDest));//EX

DataMemory MM(.OpCode(Op),.LocationFetchORStore(LocationFetchORStore),.FetchedMemData(FetchedMemData),.storeData(storeData));//MEM+WB

initial begin
    pc = 0;
end

integer i=0;
always@(*)
begin
    for (i=0;i<7;i=i+1)
    begin
        pc = i;
        Op=instruction[6:0];
        if (Op<=10) begin
            rs1= {1'b0,instruction[19:15]};
            rs2= {1'b0,instruction[24:20]};
            rd = {1'b0,instruction[11:7]};
            func3 = instruction[14:12];
            func7 = instruction[31:25];
            destReg = rd;
            
            #1;Operation = 0;
            inputreg = rs1;
            value=0;
            dataRS1 = contents;
            
            // $display("pc: %d | inputreg: %b | contents: %b", pc, inputreg,contents);

            //load value of data of register rs1... via regfile

            #1;Operation = 0;
            inputreg = rs2;
            value=0;
            dataRS2 = contents;
            //load value of data of register rs2... via regfile

            #1;Operation = 1;
            inputreg = rd;
            value = dataDest;
            //store value of data of register rd... via regfile
        end
        else if ( Op ==11) begin//lw -> I type

            //decode components of instruction
            rs1= instruction[19:15];
            rd = instruction[11:7];
            imm = instruction[31:20];
            func3 = instruction[14:12];
            destReg = rd;

            //extract data from reg file
            #1;Operation = 0;
            inputreg = rs1;
            
            // fetch data from mem
            #1;LocationFetchORStore = contents;
            LocationFetchORStore[31:0] = LocationFetchORStore[31:0] + imm[11:0];

            //store data in regfile
            #1;Operation =1;
            inputreg = rd;
            value = FetchedMemData;
        end
        else if( Op == 12)begin//sw -> S type MM [rs1 + imm][0 : 31] = rs2[0 : 31]

            //decode components of instructions
            rs1 = {1'b0,instruction[19:15]};
            rs2 = {1'b0,instruction[24:20]};
            func3 = instruction[14:12];
            imm[11:5] = instruction[31:25];
            imm[4:0] = instruction[11:7];
            destReg = 0;

            //extract data from reg file
            //for getting location for storage ...
            #1;Operation = 0;
            inputreg = rs1;
            storeData = contents;

            //for getting value to store ...
            #1;Operation = 0;
            inputreg = rs2;

            // fetch data from mem
            #1;LocationFetchORStore = contents;
            LocationFetchORStore[31:0] = LocationFetchORStore[31:0] + imm[11:0];
        end
        #10;
    end
end


endmodule


The individual codes for registerFile is
module registerFile(input Operation,input [5:0] inputreg, input [31:0] value, output reg[31:0] contents);

reg [31:0] registers [31:0];

integer i;
initial 
begin
    for(i=0;i<32;i=i+1)
    begin   
    registers[i]=i+1;
    end 
end
always@(value)
begin

    if(Operation==0)
    begin//means read value
        contents = registers[inputreg];
    end
    else 
    begin//write
        registers[inputreg] = value;
    end
end

endmodule

for alu is
module ALU(input [6:0]Op, input [31:0]a1, [31:0]b1 ,output reg [31:0] result);

reg [31:0]w1;
reg [31:0]w2;
reg [31:0]w3;
reg [31:0]w4;
reg [31:0]w5;
reg [32:0]carry;
reg [31:0]a;
reg [31:0]b;

integer i;
always@ (Op,a,b)
begin
    carry = 32'b0;
    a = a1;
    b = b1;
    case(Op)

        7'd1: 
        begin
            for(i=0;i<32;i=i+1)//addn
            begin
                w1[i] = a[i]^b[i]^carry[i];
                carry[i+1] = (a[i]^b[i])&carry[i] | a[i]&b[i];
            end
            result = {carry[32], w1};
            $display("value it came with : a= %b, b= %b result = %b",a1,b1,result);
        end
        7'd2: 
        begin
            for(i=0;i<32;i=i+1)//subtrn
            begin
                w2[i] = a[i]^(~b[i])^carry[i];
                carry[i+1] = (a[i]^(~b[i]))&carry[i] | a[i]&(~b[i]);
            end
            w2[31:0]= w2[31:0]+1'b1;
            begin
                if(w2[31])
                    begin
                        carry[32]=1;
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        carry[32]=0;
                    end
            end
            result = {carry[32], w2};
        end
        7'd3: 
        begin
            for(i=0;i<32;i=i+1)//xor
            begin
                w3[i] = a[i]^(b[i]);
            end
            result = w3;
        end
        7'd4: 
        begin
            for(i=0;i<32;i=i+1)//or
            begin
                w4[i] = a[i]|b[i];
            end
            result = w4;
        end
        7'd5: 
        begin
            for(i=0;i<32;i=i+1)//and
            begin
                w5[i] = a[i]&b[i];
            end
            result = w5;
        end
        7'd6: //sll
        begin
            //rd = rs1 << rs2
            while (b!=0) begin
                a = {a[30:0],1'b0};
                b = b - 1;
            end
            result = a;
        end
        7'd7: //srl
        begin
            //rd = rs1 >> rs2
            while (b!=0) begin
                a = {1'b0,a[31:1]};
                b = b - 1;
            end
            result = a;
        end
        7'd8: //srla
        begin
            //rd = rs1 >> rs2(sign preserved)
            while (b!=0) begin
                a = {a[31],a[31:1]};
                b = b - 1;
            end
            result = a;
        end
        7'd9: //slt
        begin
            if(a>b)begin
                result= 32'b1;
            end
            else 
            begin
                result= 32'b0;
            end
        end
        7'd10: //srlU
        begin
            if((a<b && a>0 && b>0) || (b<a && a<0 && b<0) || (b>a && a<0 && b>0))
            begin// mod(b)>mod(a)
                result= 32'b1;
            end
            else 
            begin
                result= 32'b0;
            end
        end
        default:
        carry[0]=0;
    endcase

end

endmodule

for instruction mem ->
module InstructMem(input [5:0]pc,output reg [31:0] instruction);

reg [31:0] instructions [255:0];//makes 256-> 32bit registers...// ie each 4byte.(integer size)//1kb
integer i=0;//ok
initial
begin
    instructions[0] = 32'b00000000010100011000000000000001;
    // #10;
    instructions[1] = 32'b00000000011000010000001100000001;
    // #10;
    instructions[2] = 32'b00000000010100100000000100000001;
    // #10;
    instructions[3] = 32'b00000000010100011000000100000001;
    // #10;
    instructions[4] = 32'b00000000010100011000000100000001;
    // #10;
    instructions[5] = 32'b00000000010100011000000010000001;
    // #10;
    instructions[6] = 32'b00000000010100011000000010000001;
    // #10;
    for(i=7;i<256;i=i+1)
    begin
        instructions[i] = 32'b00000000010100011000000000000000;
    end
end
assign instruction = instructions[pc];

endmodule

Data Memory
module DataMemory(input[6:0] OpCode,input [31:0]LocationFetchORStore,output reg [31:0]FetchedMemData,input [31:0] storeData);
reg [31:0] mem [255:0];//makes 256-> 32bit registers...// ie each 4byte.(integer size)//1kb

integer i;
initial
begin
    for(i=0;i<256;i=i+1)begin
        mem[i] = i+1;
    end
end
always@(OpCode,LocationFetchORStore,FetchedMemData)
begin
    if(OpCode ==11)begin//lw
        FetchedMemData = mem[LocationFetchORStore];
    end
    else begin //sw
        mem[LocationFetchORStore] = storeData;
    end
end

endmodule


I have debugged all the files other than processor and found them to be working fine... simulating each....
But the problem occurs when I try to do this :
#1;Operation = 0;
inputreg = rs1;
value=0;
dataRS1 = contents;
// $display("pc: %d | inputreg: %b | contents: %b", pc, inputreg,contents);

//load value of data of register rs1... via regfile

#1;Operation = 0;
inputreg = rs2;
value=0;
dataRS2 = contents;
//load value of data of register rs2... via regfile

#1;Operation = 1;
inputreg = rd;
value = dataDest;
//store value of data of register rd... via regfile

It is somehow not assigning anything to dataDest, which seems like an issue with ALU, but I did check it by simulating it individually. Any suggestions will help.
I have added all the folders of my project here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1r8jA5VxlMxirqClk8br87WOay8kypI8U?usp=drive_link
Anyone can open this and run processor.v directly in ModelSim.

Here is the complete waveform:


The accepted answer does resolve the target question, however there are several other related issues that need to be addressed if you intend to synthesize.
registerFile and DataMemory need a clock. As is, they infer complex level-sensitive latching logic. Simulation does care, but FPGAs normally have limited number of level-sensitive latches and ASICs will likely have timing issues. Make them proper flip-flops. A reset condition recommended, but may not be required for your situation. Example:
always @(posedge clock)
begin
    if(Operation==0)
    begin //means read value
        contents <= registers[inputreg];
    end
    else 
    begin //write
        registers[inputreg] <= value;
    end
end

The ALU is to complicated for what is needed. Use arithmetic operations for for easier to read code. A modern synthesizer will handle it without issue. There are are only a few edge cases where bit-by-bit bit-wise operations are necessary (example: school assignment).
The while keyword is not synthesizable. It is intended for non-synthesizable test benches and non-synthesizable models.
The ALU could be simplifed to something like:
always @*
begin
  carry = 1'b0;
  result = 32'b0;
  case(Op)
    // *** WARNING : ARITHMETIC ERRORS INJECTED
    // This is a coding guideline; not a free coding service
    7'd1: {carry,result} = a1 + b1; // addn
    7'd2: {carry,result} = b1 - a1; // subtrn
    7'd3: result = a1 ^ b1; // xor
    7'd4: result = a1 | b1; // or
    7'd5: result = a1 & b1; // and
    7'd6: result = a1 << b1; //sll
    7'd7: result = a1 >> b1; //srl
    7'd8: result = a1 >>> b1; //srla
    7'd9: result = a1 < b1; //slt
    7'd10: result = $signed(a1) < $signed(~b1); //srlU
  endcase
end

I am not sure what is going on with your Processor. It is written like a test bench but is also contains code that appears to be intended for a RTL design. The pc should be incremented on a clocked condition. Other then delay modeling (such as a clock model), the use of # delays are discouraged.
Combinational and sequential logic should be separated (not in the same always block; okay to be in the same module).
The instruction would be easier to understand if you code it similar to below. (Again, intends as a coding guideline only; errors are injected into the bellow code)
// direct map
wire [6:0] opcode = instruction[ 6: 0];
wire [4:0] rd     = instruction[11: 7];
wire [2:0] funct3 = instruction[14:12];
wire [4:0] rs1    = instruction[19:15];
wire [4:0] rs2    = instruction[24:20];
wire [6:0] funct7 = instruction[31:25];

// instruction type flags
wire is_r_type = (opcode <= 10);
wire is_i_type = (opcode == 11);
wire is_s_type = (opcode == 12);
wire is_b_type = (opcode >= 13) && (opcode < 16);
wire is_u_type = (opcode == 21);
wire is_j_type = (opcode >= 32);

// combinational logic for imm
reg [31:0] imm;
always @* begin
  imm = 32'b0;
  case(1'b1) // one-hot parallel case
    is_i_type : imm[11:0] = instruction[31:20];
    is_s_type : imm[11:0] = {instruction[31:25],instruction[11:7]};
    is_b_type : imm[12:1] = {instruction[31],instruction[7]:instruction[30:25],instruction[11:8]};
    is_u_type : {imm[20],imm[10:0],imm[11],imm[19:12]} = instruction[31:12];
    is_j_type : imm[31:12] = instruction[31:12];
  endcase
end

// synchrous logic
always @(posedge clock)
begin
  if (count > 3) begin
    pc <= pc+1;
    count <= 0;
  end else begin
    count <= count + 1'b1;
  end
  case(1'b1) // one-hot parallel case
  is_r_type:
    begin
      case(count)
        0 :
          begin
            // decode components of instruction
            destReg <= rd;
          end
        1 :
          begin
            // load value of data of register rs1... via regfile
            Operation <= 0;
            inputreg <= rs1;
            value<=0;
            dataRS1 <= contents;
          end
        2 :
          begin
            // load value of data of register rs2... via regfile
            Operation <= 0;
            inputreg <= rs2;
            value <=0;
            dataRS2 <= contents;
          end
        3:
         begin
            // store value of data of register rd... via regfile
            Operation <= 1;
            inputreg <= rd;
            value = dataDest;
          end
      endcase
    end
  is_i_type :
    begin //lw -> I type
      case(count)
        0 :
          begin
            //decode components of instruction
            destReg <= rd;
          end
        1 :
          begin
            //extract data from reg file
            Operation <= 0;
            inputreg <= rs1;
          end
        2 :
          begin
            // fetch data from mem
            LocationFetchORStore <= contents + imm[11:0];
          end
        3 :
          begin
            //store data in regfile
            Operation <= 1;
            inputreg <= rd;
            value = FetchedMemData;
          end
      endcase
    end
  is_s_type :
    begin//sw -> S type MM [rs1 + imm][0 : 31] = rs2[0 : 31]
      case(count)
        0 :
          begin
            //decode components of instructions
            destReg <= 0;
          end
        1 :
          begin
            //extract data from reg file
            //for getting location for storage ...
            Operation <= 0;
            inputreg <= rs1;
            storeData <= contents;
          end
        2 :
          begin
            //for getting value to store ...
            Operation <= 0;
            inputreg <= rs2;
          end
        3 :
          begin
            // fetch data from mem
            LocationFetchORStore <= contents + imm[11:0];
          end
        endcase
      end
  endcase
end

I am recommending a near total re-code. But the ends will be easier to debug and better chance it will synthesize as intended.

In the ALU module, you have an incorrect always block sensitivity list.  Change:
always@ (Op,a,b)

to:
always @*

@* is the implicit sensitivity list which automatically includes all the signals it should include (such as a1), and excludes those that should not be included (such as a).
With that change, I see this simulation output:
value it came with : a= xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, b= xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx result = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
value it came with : a= xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, b= 00000000000000000000000000000100 result = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
value it came with : a= 00000000000000000000000000000100, b= 00000000000000000000000000000100 result = 00000000000000000000000000001000
value it came with : a= 00000000000000000000000000000100, b= 00000000000000000000000000000011 result = 00000000000000000000000000000111
value it came with : a= 00000000000000000000000000000011, b= 00000000000000000000000000000011 result = 00000000000000000000000000000110
value it came with : a= 00000000000000000000000000000011, b= 00000000000000000000000000000101 result = 00000000000000000000000000001000
value it came with : a= 00000000000000000000000000000101, b= 00000000000000000000000000000101 result = 00000000000000000000000000001010
value it came with : a= 00000000000000000000000000000101, b= 00000000000000000000000000000100 result = 00000000000000000000000000001001
value it came with : a= 00000000000000000000000000000100, b= 00000000000000000000000000000100 result = 00000000000000000000000000001000


I was able to debug it by adding appropriate delays.... at places. Like I figured out that ALU processing needs time in the end... after last operation ie Operation =1 I needed to give delay so that ALU computes it and spits out the ans..... It was then giving the right answers and I owe all the credit to you and god who felt pity on me (seeing me struggle) . Sir can't I make them have 0 delay and still get them to work or does Verilog takes into account the real life delays that the circuits will have??

@Damstridium: You're welcome.  We use Verilog to crate an abstract model of digital circuits.  All real hardware circuits have delays.  In Verilog, design components, like an ALU, do not need to be modeled with a delay in them, but we do need to add delays to runs simulations.
